# Load some PostgreSQL DBMS data form a table to a csv file

Tags: postgresql, docker

There's a docker container with the db and I want to fetch the data the following way:

```
docker exec -it db psql -d swq_dev_db -U swq_dev -c 'COPY (SELECT register_email, lu.create_date, lusr."role" FROM landing_users AS lu, landing_user_subscription_role AS lusr WHERE lusr."userId" = lu.id) TO "/tmp/users.csv" DELIMITER "," CSV HEADER;'
```

Trying to do this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""/tmp/users.csv""
LINE 1: ...tion_role AS lusr WHERE lusr."userId" = lu.id) TO "/tmp/user...
```

It seems not to like the path to the file I created before running this script.

Comment: If they are not already try double single quotes(`''`) for the path and the `DELIMITER`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried this ```docker exec -it db psql -d fca_dev_db -U fca_dev -c 'COPY (SELECT register_email, lu.create_date, lusr."role" FROM landing_users AS lu, landing_user_subscription_role AS lusr WHERE lusr."userId" = lu.id) TO ''/tmp/users.csv'' DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER;'```

and got this: 

```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 1: ...tion_role AS lusr WHERE lusr."userId" = lu.id) TO /tmp/users...```

Comment: The file is in `/tmp` of your host or inside the container?

Comment: Yes, the file is there. But I got it what was wrong with the script. I should have do some escaping.

Comment: ```docker exec -it db psql -d fca_dev_db -U fca_dev -c "COPY (SELECT register_email, lu.create_date, lusr.\"role\" FROM landing_users AS lu, landing_user_subscription_role AS lusr WHERE lusr.\"userId\" = lu.id) TO '/tmp/users.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"```

This works.

Comment: Cool, you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do that. So basically, if you need to load some data from a table to some file outside the docker container inside which the DB is running, you can use the following script:

```
docker exec -it db psql -d swq_dev_db -U swq_dev -c "COPY (SELECT register_email, lu.create_date, lusr.\"role\" FROM landing_users AS lu, landing_user_subscription_role AS lusr WHERE lusr.\"userId\" = lu.id) TO '/tmp/users.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" && docker cp db:/tmp/users.csv /tmp/ && docker exec -it db rm /tmp/users.csv
```

Or more generally:

```
docker exec -it <DB_CONTAINER_NAME> psql -d <DB_NAME> -U <DB_USER> -c "COPY <SELECTION_SCRIPT> TO '<PATH_TO_FILE_IN_DB_CONTAINER>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" && docker cp <DB_CONTAINER_NAME>:<PATH_TO_FILE_IN_DB_CONTAINER> <DESTINATION_DIR_OUTISDE_DB_CONTAINER> && docker exec -it <DB_CONTAINER_NAME> rm <PATH_TO_FILE_IN_DB_CONTAINER>
```